# How to find lost iPod with no WiFi

Tags: ipod-touch, find-my-iphone

I've lost my iPod touch and I really need it. I used iCloud but it said that it has **no Wi-Fi**.

How can I find it now?

Comment: Not much we can do to help you.

Comment: If the wifi is not turned on there is no way to find it!

Answer (score 3):

Use the relevant feature in iCloud to present a message on the screen asking anyone who finds it to call you.

If anybody connects it to a wifi network without resetting the device to factory defaults, then they will get the message.

I would *not* lock or erase the device remotely, because then they will not be able to connect it to a wifi network.

Comment: Good, detailed advice.  I wonder, though, what the odds of the Touch being connected to a Wi-Fi network are—doesn't the network have to be one that it had already connected to previously?

Comment: @zigg any wifi network it connects to will do the trick, as long as the new owner doesn't wipe the device. You can also remotely disable the device, which works much better in iOS 7 than iOS 6 (Starting with 7, apple will permanently brick any device that has been remotely wiped, as a theft deterrent).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to locate an iPod Touch without it having an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you've lost it, what do you mean? It's somewhere in your home but you don't know where you put it? You might have left it somewhere? You think someone took it?

If it's around your home somewhere, you might get lucky if you have any alarms set — if you've synced your calendar to another device, check the calendar to see if there are any events with audible alarms, then listen carefully at the scheduled time — the device might make a noise revealing its location.

If you think it's in your home but it's just not reaching your WiFi signal, you could try moving the base station to different places to see if Find My iPhone works then. It's a long shot, but possible if you happened to sit it down in a corner of your home far from the base station.

Otherwise, you're probably stuck with the old-fashioned method: Where did you last see it? Retrace your steps.